# Worker role with service bus queue keeps on receiving the same message exactly 10 times

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-servicebus-queues

Worker role with service bus queue keeps on receiving the same message  exactly 10 times...
Looking likes message the queue is not being deleted or whats happening as the repetition count is exactly 10.

I am using configs.QClient.OnMessage to recieve the queued messages..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message must be marked `.Complete()` when you have finished processing otherwise it will be visible in the queue again once the lock has expired.
The default value for max delivery count is 10 after which it will dropped or moved to the dead letter queue (if option is enabled).